# Using a subset of the training data to find parameters

Tags: machine-learning, svm, mnist

I've developed some algorithms to classify digits from the MNIST dataset. The problem is these algorithms have 2 parameters and I use svm to classify which also have 2 parameters (C and gamma). It takes quite some time to find all the optimal ones. I also noted that when I use a C of 2000 I get an accuracy of 98.15% compared to an accuracy of about 90% with a C of 1, the gamma is also very high. Is it normal to have these parameters so high to get good results?

But my main question is: considering that the MNIST data is very lage, can I use a lot less digits per class (for example 1000 per class) instead of the total 60000 to have an idea about where to find good parameters? How exactly does reducing my training data influence the parameters?